# iPhone Activity App Selective Restore

Tags: iphone, apple-watch, health.app

I recently upgraded to a iPhone XR from a 7+ and transferred my Apple Watch and Health Data to the new phone. As far as I could tell when I setup the new phone everything transferred over perfectly.

I could see that all my health data transferred and when I quickly scrolled through my Activity data everything looked fine.

However, after using my new setup for a few weeks it occurred to me that my Activity Awards were behaving strangely so I took a deeper look at my Activity data and realized that a few months of Activity data did not transfer.

In summary:

- June 2018 - September 17, 2018 : Transferred
- **Sep 18, 2018 - May 1, 2019 : Skipped**
- May 2, 2019 - June 6, 2019 : Transferred
- June 7, 2019 - present : new Data created on new XR.

In the Sep 18 - May 1 range all my health data did transfer so all my Workouts show up during that time but all my Activity rings are empty and data like heart rate is missing from the workouts.

This has caused some weird results in my Awards. For example I have earned my 365 Award but only have 283 days on my 500 and 1000 Move Awards.

Does anyone have any idea how I may be able to get this data to transfer over?